# Query to find "live" videos via YouTube API only works with an unrestricted API key. Is my query wrong or am I using the wrong API library?

Tags: youtube-data-api, api-key, restriction, google-developers-console, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to write a program that queries the livestream API to see if specific channels are currently live. I am using API key auth. The query looks like this:

`/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelID}&type=video&eventType=live&key={key}`

This query works as long as the key is unrestricted. It returns a video item if the Channel is live. When I try to restrict the key to the "YouTube Data API V3" library, it does not work. No video items are returned for channels that are live.

In the documentation the livestream API looks like it falls under the Data API library, so I assumed restricting to the Data API library would still work. I cannot find a standalone livestream API library to add to the key via the developer console.

I am wondering if I am using the wrong type of query, or if there is a separate library I should be using to query the livestream API?

Comment: Make sure that the YouTube Content ID API [is enabled](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started#before-you-start) too.

Comment: @stvar I do not have that option. I am not a content partner.

Comment: Then it seems that this behavior has issues. I suggest to file a bug report to [Google](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Forgot to mention that you should link back here the bug report page such that other SO users to find it easily.

Comment: James I am having exactly the same issue.. Did you get a solution